# Best way to persist settings when application exists

Tags: c#, .net, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I have a Metro app where I need to save some data about the current "session" so that the next time the user launches my application, this session data may be restored. Some of the data is not meant for the user, but to aid in which data should be displayed right away, and which should be displayed at a later time if requested by the user.

I have been using [`LocalSettings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdata.localsettings.aspx) for other things but have just noticed that these settings only appear to last for the lifetime of the application.

How should we be storing settings that need to be saved to the App's data folder?

Comment: You should take a look at Windows 8 application life cycle: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsappdev/archive/2012/04/10/managing-app-lifecycle-so-your-apps-feel-quot-always-alive-quot.aspx & http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh986968.aspx those articles show you how to save session and other state

Comment: LocalSettings, by the way, are persistent across application instances.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve it by binding the data in to certain format , saving it in a file , retrieve it when the app launches.

- Create a ApplicationDataContainer.
- Initialize a StorageFile with the name you wish.
- Serialize your "theme/settings" object using
  DataContractSerializer.
- Write the content to the StorageFile instance created.

**On Application launch:**

- Deserialize the data.
- Populate in the way you want.

You can rather use XML as mentioned by *@Lütfullah Kus*

Answer (score 0):

you can store log to xml file like "lastform:frmSomething;lastwindow:somewindow..." and you can reload it when app start again.